# Correct implementation of Boyer Moore algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I tried to use several implementations, but all of them had bugs.
Search at SO gave me http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html - looks nice, but this implementation gave me wrong results - sometimes it doesn't found a string.
I spent couple hours to find the bug.

Following line looks fine:

```
j += MAX(bmGs[i], bmBc[y[i + j]] - m + 1 + i);
```

but *y* is char * and char is **signed**! It means that y[i + j] could be negative (what happens in one of my tests).

My question is: Where to find correct implementation of Boyer Moore algorithm?

Comment: FYI, the King of string algorithm sources is Dan Gusfield's book: Algorithms on strings, trees, and sequences.

Comment: @San Jacinto: you should make your comment as answer - the book is really good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char` isn't definitively signed *or* unsigned - it's unspecified, and left up to the implementation to define.

If the algorithm depends on char being unsigned, then it should explicitly cast the input pointers to `unsigned char` (which is how the C standard library string handling functions are defined to work - all comparisons are done treating the characters in the string as `unsigned char`).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)?

Or the [PDF written by the inventors of the algorithm](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/publications/fstrpos.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

As of C++17, this is built into the STL. Just use [`std::boyer_moore_searcher`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher). For example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::string haystack = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
    std::string needle = "brown";
    const auto s = std::boyer_moore_searcher<std::string::iterator>(needle.begin(), needle.end());
    const auto it = std::search(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), s);
    return 0;
}
```