# Boyer Moore Algorithm Implementation?

Tags: c, string-matching, boyer-moore

Is there a working example of the Boyer-Moore string search algorithm in C?
I've looked at a few sites, but they seem pretty buggy, including wikipedia.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think the Wikipedia version is buggy? (I haven't bothered running it myself, which is why I'm asking.)

Comment: via an answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251465/correct-implementation-of-boyer-moore-algorithm

Answer (score 4):

The best site for substring search algorithms:

http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/

Comment: I've seen that site, but the implementation is very terse and does not include a main, so I'm having trouble following it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I can't think of any reason you'd want an implementation of BM as a standalone program, especially when you can't figure out how to make a simple function call yourself, unless you're trying to turn it in as homework and pass it off as your own work...

Comment: I'm trying to understand how it works well enough to program it myself. I understand the basic concept to some extent, but when I sit down and think of how to actually write it in C, i get confused. The code doesn't have comments, and I am having trouble understanding what each function is for, or in what order I would make calls etc.

Comment: Look at the `BM` function. The other functions are all called from it, and never need to be called stand-alone. Its arguments are simple: the needle and haystack strings and their lengths.

Comment: here is the output when i try to compile, my main is simply a basic call to BM. http://pastebin.com/5tuhmRzh there seems to be a lot of constants which weren't defined (and I'm not sure what they are meant to be). Also there are some warnings and unused variables which makes me wonder if this is a bug-free implementation.

Comment: `OUTPUT` should be defined to a macro to output the match. `MAX` should have the obvious definition. The `SIZE` macros may be hard-coded size limits which you of course need to fix (but a fundamental flaw of BM is that it cannot be implemented in constant size).

Comment: And as the for the warnings and unused variables?

Comment: The `char` subscript is probably an error. Should cast to `unsigned char` or better yet use `unsigned char *` everywhere. Most if not all of the other warnings came from failure to define the macros, I think.

Comment: I agree with Blackbinary in that the site mentioned does not give much clue as to how to use the thing. "Its arguments are simple: the needle and haystack strings and their lengths". Simple when you already know.  Why doesn't it just say that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C90 implementation that I have stressed with a lot of strange test cases:

```
#ifndef MAX
#define MAX(a,b)  ((a > b) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

void  fillBadCharIndexTable (
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------
    function:
       the table fits for 8 bit character only (including utf-8)
    parameters: */
    size_t  aBadCharIndexTable [],
    char const *  const pPattern,
    size_t  const patternLength)
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
    size_t  i;
    size_t  remainingPatternLength = patternLength - 1;

    for (i = 0;  i < 256; ++i) {
        aBadCharIndexTable [i] = patternLength;
    }
    for (i = 0;  i < patternLength;  ++i) {
        aBadCharIndexTable [pPattern [i]] = remainingPatternLength--;
    }
}

void  fillGoodSuffixRuleTable (
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------
    function:
       the table fits for patterns of length < 256; for longer patterns ... (1 of)
       - increase the static size
       - use variable length arrays and >= C99 compilers
       - allocate (and finally release) heap according to demand
    parameters: */
    size_t  aGoodSuffixIndexTable [],
    char const *  const pPattern,
    size_t  const patternLength)
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
    size_t  const highestPatternIndex = patternLength - 1;
    size_t  prefixLength = 1;

    /* complementary prefix length, i.e. difference from highest possible pattern index and prefix length */
    size_t  cplPrefixLength = highestPatternIndex;

    /* complementary length of recently inspected pattern substring which is simultaneously pattern prefix and suffix */
    size_t  cplPrefixSuffixLength = patternLength;

    /* too hard to explain in a C source ;-) */
    size_t  iRepeatedSuffixMax;

    aGoodSuffixIndexTable [cplPrefixLength] = patternLength;

    while (cplPrefixLength > 0) {
        if (!strncmp (pPattern,  pPattern + cplPrefixLength,  prefixLength)) {
            cplPrefixSuffixLength = cplPrefixLength;
        }

        aGoodSuffixIndexTable [--cplPrefixLength] = cplPrefixSuffixLength + prefixLength++;
    }

    if (pPattern [0] != pPattern [highestPatternIndex]) {
        aGoodSuffixIndexTable [highestPatternIndex] = highestPatternIndex;
    }

    for (iRepeatedSuffixMax = 1;  iRepeatedSuffixMax < highestPatternIndex;  ++iRepeatedSuffixMax) {
        size_t  iSuffix = highestPatternIndex;
        size_t  iRepeatedSuffix = iRepeatedSuffixMax;

        do {
            if (pPattern [iRepeatedSuffix] != pPattern [iSuffix]) {
                aGoodSuffixIndexTable [iSuffix] = highestPatternIndex - iRepeatedSuffix;
                break;
            }

            --iSuffix;
        } while (--iRepeatedSuffix > 0);
    }
}

char const *  boyerMoore (
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------
    function:
       find a pattern (needle) inside a text (haystack)
    parameters: */
    char const *  const pHaystack,
    size_t  const haystackLength,
    char const *  const pPattern)
    /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/
{
    size_t  const patternLength = strlen (pPattern);
    size_t  const highestPatternIndex = patternLength - 1;
    size_t  aBadCharIndexTable [256];
    size_t  aGoodSuffixIndexTable [256];

    if (*pPattern == '\0') {
        return pHaystack;
    }

    if (patternLength <= 1) {
        return strchr (pHaystack,  *pPattern);
    }

    if (patternLength >= sizeof aGoodSuffixIndexTable) {
        /* exit for too long patterns */
        return 0;
    }

    {
        char const *  pInHaystack = pHaystack + highestPatternIndex;

        /* search preparation */
        fillBadCharIndexTable (
            aBadCharIndexTable,
            pPattern,
            patternLength);
        fillGoodSuffixRuleTable (
            aGoodSuffixIndexTable,
            pPattern,
            patternLength);

        /* search execution */
        while (pInHaystack++ < pHaystack + haystackLength) {
            int  iPattern = (int) highestPatternIndex;

            while (*--pInHaystack == pPattern [iPattern]) {
                if (--iPattern < 0) {
                    return pInHaystack;
                }
            }

            pInHaystack += MAX (aBadCharIndexTable [*pInHaystack],  aGoodSuffixIndexTable [iPattern]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't `patternLength >= sizeof aGoodSuffixIndexTable` be `patternLength >= sizeof(aGoodSuffixIndexTable) / sizeof(size_t)` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of implementations of Boyer-Moore-Horspool (including Sunday's variant) on Bob Stout's [Snippets](http://www.snippets.org) site. Ray Gardner's implementation in [BMHSRCH.C](http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=bmhsrch.c) is bug-free as far as I know<sup>1</sup>, and definitely the fastest I've ever seen or heard of. It's not, however, the easiest to understand -- he uses some fairly tricky code to keep the inner loop as a simple as possible. I may be biased, but I think my version<sup>2</sup> in [PBMSRCH.C](http://c.snippets.org/snip_lister.php?fname=pbmsrch.c) is a bit easier to understand (though definitely a bit slower).

<sup>1</sup> Within its limits -- it was originally written for MS-DOS, and could use a rewrite for environments that provide more memory.
<sup>2</sup> This somehow got labeled as "Pratt-Boyer-Moore", but is actually Sunday's variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool (though I wasn't aware of it at the time and didn't publish it, I believe I actually invented it about a year before Sunday did).

Comment: sadly the Horspool algorithm isn't the same as standard BM, from what I understand.

Comment: @Blackbinary: no, it's not the same algorithm -- it's a simplified version. Although the original B-M algorithm is theoretically better (uses fewer comparisons) the initial setup is enough more complex that it's *usually* slower.

Comment: Sadly, it looks like the Snippets site is no more.

Comment: @DavidConrad: Unfortunately that's true; it's gone. If you search for `snip9707.zip`, it's pretty easy to find copies of (nearly) the most recent version though.