# searching a string for a character string in C

Tags: c

I need to search a random list of characters in the form of a string for the occurrence of a certain string of characters. this function is to return a pointer to the character after the last character in the search list. in my main function I need to loop the function and return a count of the occurrences of the search string in the random list.

here is my function thus far.

```
char *findStringInData(char *data, char *string){
    int x, i;
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    char *follower;
    char *temp;
    for (x = 0; data[x] != '\0'; x++){
        if (data[x]== string[x]){
            temp = &data[x];
            //m++;
        }
            for(i = data[x]; string[i] != '\0'; i++){
            if (data[i] == string[i])
            follower = &temp[i];
            //n++;
            //printf("the count is %d\n", n);
        }
    }
    return follower;

   return NULL; 
}
```

Comment: Why not just use [`strstr(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strstr/)?

Comment: Maybe the OP is on an embedded platform without a standard library.

Comment: @FUZxxl, the newlib implementation of `strstr` is about 12 lines of meaningful code (ie, not braces or blank lines).  If the OP is without a standard library, he could certainly take that one function without problems.  It appears, however, that he *does* have a standard library, since his program calls `printf`, though it does happen to be commented out.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't reimplement the standard library, which has strstr() for this purpose.

Depending on your input data and the strings you're searching for, you could also consider specialized methods of string searching, like Boyer-Moore (see [Boyer Moore Algorithm Implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423886/boyer-moore-algorithm-implementation))

Comment: I cannot use any thing from the string library to search or compare. this is the whole reason it is giving me issues.

Comment: @WillHumble, you can get a strstr implementation from newlib or glibc withough too much trouble.  Can you explain better exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have another method that fills a character string with random characters and then the search string method looks for the occurrence of a certain character string with in that character string. in my main i am to loop the search method and increment a counter each time the searchString is found.